Independence between random vectors.
I have been studying stochastic processes, and I have come across the following definition:
Two stochastic processes $X$ and $Y$ are independent if the vectors made of the random variables $(X1, X2,...,Xn)$ and $(Y1,Y2,..., Yn)$ are independent.
I am wondering what does that mean. $Xi$ must be independent of all indexed variables $Yn$ , or must it only be independent with the corresponding variable $Yi$ ?

Context matters here.  Obviously, it's possible that those two vectors are dependent regardless of $X,Y$.  So...what do you mean?

There are only two vectors here $(X_1,X_2, \dots, X_n)$ and $(Y_1,Y_2, \dots , Y_n)$. The individual variables don't tell you anything about their linear independence in isolation.

The first one is the right one. 'Corresponging ' does not even make sense since the index sets may be different.

This question is similar to: Independent stochastic processes and independent random vectors. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
